# jQuery tabs() function not displaying tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

The following is my HTML code for creating a tabbed page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
  <title>Testing Tabs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#panel1">Panel 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel2">Panel 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel3">Panel 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="panel1">
        <p>This is the text of panel 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2">
        <p>This is the text of panel 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="panel3">
        <p>This is the text of panel 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I execute the command $('#tabs').tabs() (or $('#tabs').tabs({})) at the Firebug CommandLine, nothing really happens i.e. the links remain links, and all the divs are displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you include the jQueryUI stylesheet as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6kg7k/